# Too many changes in a PR submitted to master

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I just created a PR. Unfortunately I needed changes from `master` so I pulled from `master`. Now when I create a PR all changes (including the ones from the `master` branch) are shown.

Is it possible to just show the changes I actually made?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're submitting a PR against master, rebase on top of it:

```
$ git checkout my-branch
$ git fetch --all
$ git rebase origin/master
$ git push -f
```

If you've added `upstream` as a remote, use `upstream/master` instead.